# How can I input '#' character in the beginning of a line?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

How can I input the '#' character in the beginning of a line?

just like:

## include

the '#' character automatically disappeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites use [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/); `#` marks at the beginning of the line indicate a [header](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#headers). If you're typing [code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), indent it by four spaces and it will be formatted properly (and possibly syntax highlighted, depending on the language):

```
#include
```

You can also highlight a block of code and press the "Code Sample" (`{}`) button in the toolbar above, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, and it will indent all the selected lines

---

If it's not code and you really just want a `#` at the beginning of the line for some reason, you can also escape it with a `\`:

#include

I can't think of any legitimate need for that though